# change current tab after calling tabactivity by intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I am having a Tabactivity with two tabs  and I am calling this tab activity from other activities ..but I want to set tab according to activity from where tab activity has been called .For that I have used intent flag SINGLE TOP and override onNewIntent() in Tabactivity  so that I can find from where Tabactivity has been called and set tab according to that but my onNewIntent() is not getting called ..dont know why ..I have  also mentioned launch mode SINGLE TOP ..Here is my Code for intent and onNewINtent().
Is there any other way to do this..

```
Intent i =new   Intent(Activity1.this,TabViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("show","mytab");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("new Intent","new intent has came ");
        if(intent.getExtras().getString("show").equalsIgnoreCase("mytab"))
        {
              View tabView = getTabWidget().getChildAt(0);
              tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabSelectedDivider).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);   
        }

        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) { 
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

can use this also inside oncreate no need for onNewIntent().